# RxJava - sequential call of two methods in background and return values in main thread

Tags: android, multithreading, rx-java

I would like to call `getNote` in background.

After I get result which is a `Note` object and still in background I would like to take  two `Note's` values - `text_encrypted` and `date`.

After all I would like to return them to next step and in main thread set values on two textViews.

How could I achive this? Here is my code below.

```
Observable.fromCallable(() -> NotesDataBase.getNote(id))
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .flatMap(notes -> {
        new Object[]{
                GeneratorAES.decrypt(notes.text_encrypted),
                CalendarUtils.showArticleTime(notes.date)
        };
    })
    .subscribe(objects -> {
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2)).setText(objects[0]);
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1)).setText(objects[1]);
    });
```

I assume I am doing something wrong in first flatMap but I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should not compile since `flatMap()` requires you to return an observable from your lambda. Additionally `observeOn()` will change the thread for all following operations of the chain.

Instead you have to call `observeOn()` after your operations and only `map()` the values. To make it nicer, you could also use `Pair` instead of `Object[]`:

```
Observable.fromCallable(() -> NotesDataBase.getNote(id))
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .map(notes -> Pair.create(
                GeneratorAES.decrypt(notes.text_encrypted),
                CalendarUtils.showArticleTime(notes.date)))
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(pair -> {
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2)).setText(pair.first());
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1)).setText(pair.second());
    });
```

Comment: Thanks! Could You tell me how could I modify Your code for situation when the first method in thread doesn't return anything but the second does?

Comment: Basing on Your answer how to handle situation when the `NotesDataBase.getNote(id)` returns void?

Comment: You can represent it with a `Maybe.fromCallable()`.